# Cannot get 4K@120Hz gaming to work on the TV connected to PC

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, desktop-computer, tv

I'm trying to connect my TV to PC and use it for 4k 120Hz gaming. I have PC with RTX 3080 and TV LG OLED 55B2 2023 version. I bought connection cable like this https://www.amazon.com.be/-/en/PremiumCord-Optical-48Gbps-Resolution-Plated/dp/B089GZHMQS. I successfully connected the TV, but in games, the best possible resolution was 4K on 60 Hz or 1440p on 120Hz. Does anybody knows why? All of the components should meet the criteria for the 4K@120Hz gaming.

P.S.: I use HDMI cable also to pass sound not only video.

Comment: Do you get 120Hz when not in a game but on the desktop for example?

Comment: @zomega I did not check that, I do believe that not (in monitor settings i think on 4k I saw only 60Hz), but the cable died (I probably stepped on it bad) so I can't check now. I'm going to buy new one which is why I decided to check if I'm doing everything OK.

Comment: All your components are of high quality and support 4K at 120 Hz, at least by the documentation. If their combination does not work for gaming, you would need to find which one is the cause, and the only way is by testing (as in the comment by @zomega) or by trying other components. What were the symptoms when it didn't work (before you stepped on the cable)?

Comment: Check in the device manager that you are using a NVidia driver and not generic Microsoft stuff. Also if you have integrated graphics I recommend disabling it in the UEFI settings.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback. I will check the driver, but I think it is the latest NVidia driver otherwise I would have problem running games at highest FPS with some default MIcrosoft driver. There should not be any integrated graphics. The only symptom for 120Hz not working was that the selection in games showed maximally 4k@60Hz and I believe the same was for windows settings. Now I know that the components themselves should be OK, so I can try to buy new cable of the one I destroyed and test once again. I will try to get back here to report my results once I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was simple (I forgot to report once I figured it out). There are 4 connectors total, I mounted the TV on the wall, so I saw only 2 side HDMI, which did not support 120Hz. But there are two more, they both support 4K@120Hz and I believe port number 3 is the best as it support also better sound quality over the cable.